# Warnings (or other means) to identify potential unsigned integer overflows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang++, gcc-warning

There are some cases where potential unsigned integer overflows might cause issues. This example illustrates one:

```
struct Image
{
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
    uint32_t depth;
};

void* allocateMemory(size_t);

...

allocateMemory(f.width * f.height * f.depth);
```

The x64 disassembly of GCC, clang and MSVC shows that the multiplications will be done using 32bit arithmetic. This might result into an overflow when there is a long list of multiplications.

```
mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi + 4]
imul    eax, dword ptr [rdi]
imul    eax, dword ptr [rdi + 8]
mov     rdi, rax
```

This godbolt link contains the above example and the disassembly of the 3 popular compilers: https://godbolt.org/z/1P1bT3jj6

I've enabled all possible warnings on GCC and clang (including -Weverything) but none reports issues in the above code. Only MSVC reported it inside the editor (`C26451 Arithmetic overflow: Using operator * ...`) but I haven't managed to make it report that while building.

So the question is how to catch these types of issues when building the code (no runtime checks). Is there a static analysis tool that can catch this? Or maybe a way to have this Intellisense `C26451` warning being reported when building with MSVC?

Comment: I know how to fix the issue. The question is how to know that there is an issue to fix.

Comment: The standard specifies what happens to unsigned types on overflow (i.e. modulo arithmetic aka "wrap around").   So, if it is possible to configure your compiler (or some other component of your toolset) to issue such warnings, what do you want to do in cases where behaviour specified by the standard is the INTENDED outcome?

Comment: As far as the standard goes, there is no such thing as unsigned integer overflow. Unsigned types implement modular arithmetic. In C++ you can wrap your integers in a custom class that e.g. disallows multiplication or performs it in higher width, while passing other arithmetic operations through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MSVC, you can enable warnings such as C26451 *while building* by enabling "Code Analysis" in the project's (or file's) properties<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

Alternatively, you can run that code analysis on an open/active file *at any time* using the "Run Code Analysis on File" command from the "Build" menu (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>).

---

You can enable this option on the command-line using the `/analyze` switch; however, you will need to specify the code analysis "plugins" (which ship with Visual Studio) to use (a typical option would be along the lines of `/analyze:plugin EspxEngine.dll`). An overview of these is given on [this Microsoft web-page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/analyze-code-analysis?view=msvc-160), in the "Analysis plugin options" section. The following paragraph appears particularly relevant:

> When you build on the command line, you can use the Esp.Extensions
> environment variable to specify EspXEngine extensions. For
> example:
>  `set Esp.Extensions=ConcurrencyCheck.dll;CppCoreCheck.dll;`

---

<sup>1</sup> But note, this option will increase build times *considerably*, which may become problematic for large projects.

Comment: Any idea how to turn that on from the command line (I'm using CMake)? I believe it's `/analyze` but testing on gotbolt doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Pan  Hmm. Not entirely sure. Turning off the option shown above and adding the `/analyze` switch in the compiler command-line options (in a real VS, not on Compiler Explorer) also doesn't show the C26451 warning. Probably need to specify a ruleset file, and that may not be available to the online compilers.

Comment: @Pan.ChristopoulosCharitos ... Yep! Using the `/analyze:plugin EspxEngine.dll` command-line option works.